# EXCEL code to tidy up a report sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel 2007. I have built a userform which writes data to several sheets within the workbook. In a sheet name `Reports` I want to create a command button `Cmdtomorrows` to delete all rows on the report sheet apart from the rows beginning with tomorrows date  `(Now() + 1, "DD/MM/YYYY")`.

The dates are recorded in `Column A`:

Example: tomorows date is `21/11/2011` so I want the command button to delete entries for rows starting with dates 19 and `10/11/2011`. I have unsuccessfully tried to record a macro for this. The Macro generally gives me a head start with the VBA code for the button. In previous Questions I have been able to post my code and have got help, but not sure where to start with this one.

I can't show any sample table.

Answer (score 3):

This code can be attached to your command button. It loops through all of the "used" rows on the sheet "Reports" and deletes the entire row if the value in column A is not tomorrow's date. Note the use of the Fix function to truncate any time component. If you want to keep rows where the date is tomorrow's date or later, change the <> comparison to just <.

Also note that this code assumes that the values in Column A are all dates.

```
Sub DeleteAllButTomorrows()
    Dim lRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Reports")
        lRow = 2    ' first row after header row
        Do While lRow <= .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Fix(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value) <> Date + 1 Then
                .Rows(lRow).Delete
            Else
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```